# Encrypt a field if changed with findOneAndUpdate middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, schema, middleware

I'm confused. Mongoose allows us to use methods `update`, `findOneAndUpdate`... etc however when passing through a **middleware** like `pre('findOneAndUpdate')` we only have access to the query. For example, the `isModified` method isn't available.

How am I supposed to **encrypt a field if changed** and edit a timestamp in the model if anything else changed?

Comment: Stackoverflow removes my greeting at the beginning of the subject...

Comment: It is best to add this and similar information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had to progress in my project. Finally I use the `findOne` method then `save` and I implemented encryption and deciphering in the accessors of my field. (the `pre('save', ...)` middleware also works but in my context it is less suitable).

Thanks anyway